# Centralized IIS to redirect to other IIS servers

Tags: windows, webserver, web, iis, url

Basically what im after is to have a centralized IIS Server on the Local LAN where port 80/443 would be forwarded to from the router. Then through this server it can forward/redirect the requests to other servers in order to access the exchange OWA and for example the Remote Desktop web apps which are located on other local servers, the Exchange server and RDS Server respectively? For example I would access www.example.com and redirect me directly to this IIS centralized Server and www.example.com/OWA will redirect me to the Exchange server and www.example.com/RDWEB will redirect me to the RDS server. I need to know if such setup can be done so that I can have one main domain (example.com) and also one public IP Address corresponding

Answer (score -2):

This can be done via Forefront TMG.  There is also a smaller component that you can add to Windows that will handle reverse proxies, which is essentially what you are asking for.  I forgot the name but some googling of "reverse proxy windows component" should find it.

Comment: Forefront Threat Management Gateway is [no longer available](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/forefront/ee807302), and even if it were your answer would be more helpful if you described what it is and how it helps answer the question asked. Suggesting somebody "google something" is not a very helpful answer either.